# HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL - SOAP

Tags: java, .net, xml, web-services, soap

I am using a SOAP service / client ( which is .NET) that sends XML envelopes to a SOAP UI service (Java I am guessing) however, we are getting a 405 saying method is not allowed, looking into fiddler, the error is actually `HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL` however this confuses me when using SOAP, I thought it uses POST by default as using a GET would put the XML inside the URL which is crazy. Does anyone know if I can change something in the client or in the service?

Comment: You don't know which verbs the service exposes?

Comment: It isnt our service - hence why the question is a bit generic.  When using fidder and using SOAP UI to test it, the headers does say POST, which is what is making us confused

Comment: The header of your request? That's OK, but you need to ask the owner of the service you're calling what is the verb you need to query his service by.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had a similar issue in SoapUi 5.2.1.  I've exposed 30+ web service methods through Java on Jboss EAP 7.  Originally I had 4 only exposed in my SoapUi project.  When I re-updated/consumed the updated WSDL, the 26 new methods showed in SoapUi.  I filled in all the sample requests with the needed arguments.  I then created a "Test Suite" consisting of test cases for each of the new methods which "inherited" the arguments I had populated in the default requests (time saver!).

I executed the test suite.  Everything passed as green, but looking at the resulting web service responses almost all of them had:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL</body>
</html>
```

As the SOAP response.  I dug around a bit, it turned out to be only the new methods I had added, the four original worked fine.  Looking at the SOAP endpoint, I realized I had modified the web service slightly and instead of the endpoint being:
http://localhost:8080/MyServicesR20/AdvancedBusinessService

It was now:
http://localhost:8080/MyServicesR20/AdvancedBusiness

For some reason when SoapUi updated the definition it didnt use the original endpoint for all the new requests and instead an older one.  I manually went and changed each to be the correct endpoint and now all the web service requests work as expected.

Note and hindsight, if you have a large number of requests and or test cases and end up changing the endpoint, just back up the XML document that SoapUi uses for the project, then perform a search and replace of the old endpoint with the new endpoint to save yourself a lot of trouble!